# Trying to Update Open API Spec from 2.0 to 3.0 But YAML Still Evaluates as 2.0.

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I am trying to update my local swagger project from OpenAPI 2.0 to OpenAPI 3.0.

I am getting a ton of errors which imply that I my YAML file is still being evaluated as OAS2.0:

```
Project Errors
--------------
#/: Missing required property: swagger
#/: Additional properties not allowed: components,servers,openapi
#/paths/~1auth~1info~1firebase/get/responses/200: Not a valid response definition
#/paths/~1posts~1{id}~1comments/get/responses/200: Not a valid response definition
#/paths/~1posts~1{id}~1comments/get/parameters/2: Not a valid parameter definition
#/paths/~1posts~1{id}~1comments/get/parameters/1: Not a valid parameter definition
#/paths/~1posts~1{id}~1comments/get/parameters/0: Not a valid parameter definition
#/paths/~1users~1{id}~1profile/get/responses/200: Not a valid response definition
I have updated swagger-ui-express to the latest version.
```

Below are the relevant parts of my server.js file:

```
const YAML = require('yamljs');
const swaggerDocument = YAML.load('./api/swagger/swagger.yaml');
const SwaggerExpress = require('swagger-express-mw');
const swaggerUI = require('swagger-ui-express');
const api = express();

let swaggerConfig = 
{
  appRoot: __dirname
}
let swaggerOptions = 
{ 
  explorer: true 
};

api.use('/api/v1/docs/endpoints',
  swaggerUI.serve,
  swaggerUI.setup(swaggerDocument, swaggerOptions)
);

SwaggerExpress.create(swaggerConfig, function(err, swaggerExpress) {
   if (err) { throw err; }
   // install middleware
   swaggerExpress.register(api);
});
```

I have updated swagger-ui-express and swagger-express-mw to the latest versions.

But I am still getting the above errors.

I am thinking that the way forward may be to not use swagger-ui-express
and rework my code for swagger-ui but I see online that people seem to 
get things working with that npm module.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: swagger-express does not support OpenAPI 3.0 yet: https://github.com/apigee-127/swagger-express/issues/20

Comment: So, what is the appropriate set-up to get OAS 3.0 working with node.js? Any suggestions? I am still not clear on the appropriate npm modules, code, etc to get this working on localhost. Thanks for any suggestions.